# Spell check for latex file in Atom

Tags: latex, atom-editor, tex

I am trying to add .tex file in the Setting->Grammar of atom/spell-check so that it will check spellings in my document because .tex file is going to be a PDF document, but its not working.

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Found out that I was using wrong syntax. Correct scope is `text.tex.latex`. It was already mentioned in the README file on how to get it. Follow below procedure in Atom Editor.

> To enable Spell Check for your current file type: put your cursor in
>   the file, open the Command Palette (`cmd-shift-p`), and run the
>   `Editor: Log Cursor Scope` command. This will trigger a notification
>   which will contain a list of scopes. The first scope that's listed is
>   the one you should add to the list of scopes in the settings for the
>   Spell Check package. Here are some examples: `source.coffee,text.plain, text.html.basic.`

[image]

It should pop up as below
[image]

Comment: Once you have spell-checking enabled in LaTeX files, soon, like me, you'll wish there was a built-in list of LaTeX commands that won't annoy the default spell checker.

Comment: @DavidJ. Have you found a fix for this?

Comment: @DavidJ. you are right! it is annoying and there is no solution as far as I know.

Comment: @DavidJ. According to https://acarril.github.io/posts/atom-latex, there is a solution for this: you can paste the following code directly in your config.cson file (Edit > Config...):

"spell-check":
  excludedScopes: [
    "support.function.tex"
    "meta.preamble.latex"
    "support.type.function.latex"
    "comment.line.percentage.tex"
    "storage.type.function.latex"
    "support.function.latex"
    "string.other.math.tex"
    "string.other.math.block.environment.latex"
    "variable.parameter.function.latex"
    "constant.other.reference.latex"
  ]